# Is constant value evaluated at compile time in Go?

Tags: go, constants

If I have something like:

```
const a = 1 + 1
```

Is `1 + 1` added during the compiling time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yes*

> **Constant expressions** may contain only constant operands and **are
>   evaluated at compile time**.

Check [constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).